# Receiving "Could not install application" when using NativeScript Sidekick to Build Application

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm in the process of developing an Android and iOS Mobile Application, but for the last day or so, I haven't been able to get the app to build and run on my mobile device. Prior to this everything was running smoothly.

The single error message that I am currently receiving is:

```
[19-04-03 09:33:18.551] Error detected during LiveSync on PLACEHOLDERDeviceID for /Volumes/Data Stuff/GIT/mypet. Error: Failed to install /Volumes/Data Stuff/GIT/mypet/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/mypet.ipa on device with identifier PLACEHOLDERDeviceID. Error is: Could not install application
```

which... isn't helping me determine a root cause as to why I'm getting nowhere.

I don't suppose anyone else has experienced this or can think of a way for me to get a more verbose explanation as to what's happening so I can try and track down (and resolve) whatever issue I'm having?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the right iOS certificates & provisional profile setup for your device?

Comment: I hadn't changed anything in the run up to this being an issue, and don't recall having set anything up previously on this front, and it was working fine. I've since gone through and provided what seem to be the correct certificates and provisioning profiles, but with no change to the core issue.